# My code needs SELECT while I used only INSERTS

Tags: c#, mysql, permissions

**SCENARIO**

Hello, I'm programming in C# an application that backups (with INSERTS/UPDATES only) some small data from one database from A to B with different ip.

On database A, I perform SELECT queries to buffer all the data in a List which works really smooth. To transfer to B, in the same function I perform a foreach with INSERTS and UPDATES inside it to store registers one by one.

**PROBLEM**

I don't want user on database (and server) B to have permissions to SELECT anything. 'SHOW GRANTS' displays that the user has SELECT, INSERT and UPDATE for *.*.

So whenever I revoke the SELECT (tested by 'SHOW GRANTS'), in MySQL workbench the user will act normally (cannot SELECT). But in the code, it will throw an exception saying I have no permissions to work.

**INFORMATION**

- I'm using MySQL 5.7.14.
- Programming in C#, WindowsFormsApp.
- To read the data from Server A, I use MySqlConnection, MySqlDataReader and MySqlCommand.
- To INSERT/UPDATE on Server B (where the problem is), I use MySqlConnection  and MySqlCommand with ExecuteNonQuery().

**QUESTION**

I think that the problem is that ExecuteNonQuery() function does the following:

> Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns the number of rows affected.

Taken from manual. "[...] returns the number of rows affected" sounds like it performs a SELECT somewhere to get that data.

Does it? How can I prevent this?

Comment: related, unfortunately not very helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40373677/1132334

Comment: and also https://stackoverflow.com/q/8828139/1132334

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_select => SELECT privilege is needed in UPDATE statements for any columns referenced in the where clause, or if the update itself assigns to a column being read.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I was able to find an alternative solution. So in the end, does the ExecuteNonQuery() performs a SELECT? You shall merge all this into an answer.

Comment: @steve16351 this was it!